# selection border is incorrect while canvas's zoom value is not 1

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Version 2.3.6

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. click 'select-all', selection is all right.
2. next click 'set zoom as 1.5' ,
3. then click 'select-all',

**Result:** Selection border is incorrect now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 75,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    padding: 10
  }));

  canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
    left: 120,
    top: 120,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'gray',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 3
  }));


  $("#select-all").click(function() {
    canvas.discardActiveObject();
    var elements = canvas.getObjects();
    var selection = new fabric.ActiveSelection(elements);
    canvas.setActiveObject(selection);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  });

  $("#set-zoom-15").click(function() {
    canvas.setZoom(1.2);
  });
  $("#set-zoom-10").click(function() {
    canvas.setZoom(1.0);
  });
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.min.js"></script>


<input id="select-all" type="button" value="select all" />
<input id="set-zoom-15" type="button" value="set zoom as 1.5" />
<input id="set-zoom-10" type="button" value="set zoom as 1" />
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid red" />
```

**Expected Behavior:**
Selection works fine ( like zoom is 1 ) when the zoom is 1.5.

**Actual Behavior:**
Selection is incorrect when the zoom is 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your `ActiveSelection`, you need to pass in the `canvas` object.

```
var selection = new fabric.ActiveSelection(elements, {
   canvas: canvas,
});
```

See http://fabricjs.com/manage-selection for documentation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 75,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    padding: 10
  }));

  canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
    left: 120,
    top: 120,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'gray',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 3
  }));


  $("#select-all").click(function() {
    canvas.discardActiveObject();
    var elements = canvas.getObjects();
    var selection = new fabric.ActiveSelection(elements, {
      canvas: canvas,
    });
    canvas.setActiveObject(selection);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  });

  $("#set-zoom-15").click(function() {
    canvas.setZoom(1.2);
  });
  $("#set-zoom-10").click(function() {
    canvas.setZoom(1.0);
  });
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.min.js"></script>


<input id="select-all" type="button" value="select all" />
<input id="set-zoom-15" type="button" value="set zoom as 1.5" />
<input id="set-zoom-10" type="button" value="set zoom as 1" />
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid red" />
```

Comment: Thanks vary mach, This problem blocked me for one day.